# No sé cómo pasar un input a una variable en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que lo que se escribe dentro del textarea se escriba abajo después y no sé cómo, soy nuevo en esto, este es mi código:

```js
var nombre = document.getElementById("hi");
setInterval(function() {
  document.write(nombre);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<textarea id="hi">hola</textarea>
```

Comment: abajo en que parte, en algún div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría de este modo:

**PROCESO**

Antes te propongo crear un `div` debajo de tu `textarea` para que ese sea el espacio destinado a actuar como receptor de la info. que en el textarea sea generada

1. Obtengo el `value` ingresado en el `textarea` y lo asigno a una variable
2. Después obtendría un `div` a través de su `id` por que ahi es donde voy a volcar toda la data que el usuario este escribiendo en el textarea
3. Ambas variables arriba mencionadas, las meteré en una función `setInterval` que se ejecutará cada 100 milisegundos para evitar latencia y que los cambios se vean continuos
4. Con ayuda de `innerHTML` le asigno al `div` con id app el valor que se esta escribiendo en el textarea y como este proceso esta dentro de la función antes mencionada, será un proceso completo que se repita cada 100 milisegundos

**CÓDIGO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea name="" id="texto" cols="30" rows="10">
    </textarea>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script>
          setInterval(function(){
            let cuadro = document.getElementById("texto").value
            let lienzo = document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = cuadro
          }, 100)
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: En vez de hacerlo con `setInterval`, ¿No sería más recomendable insertar la función en un evento que se ejecute cuando cambie o se escriba en el `textarea`?

Comment: también es válido @Rabegi si tienes otra forma de resolverlo te invito a quela publiques como respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas esta linea de código `var nombre = document.getElementById("hi")` obtienes un objeto. El texto que quieres extraer esta en el atributo `value` si pones `nombre.value; // obtendrás "Hola"`. Estabas por buen camino. Saludos

Comment: Respuesta muy corta, la idea es ser claro

Comment: Hola @shadow yo veo perfecta la respuesta.

Comment: @SebastianPaduano no dije que no fuera válida dije que es muy corta y la idea es expresarla mas amplia, tan la considero que esta bien empezada que por eso le di +1

Answer (score 0):

Usa:

```
nombre.value
```

> *getElementById* te retorna el elemento completo, en javascript lo puedes utilizar como un objeto y utilizar sus propiedades